# Codeception- cannot run dump.sql- (Exception in Db) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, codeception

When I run my acceptance test, I get the error below.  If I don't have anything in the dump.sql, then the test runs.  Inside the test, I am able to reach the database.  The database creds are identical in the two files below.  Am I right that the dump.sql load uses the acceptance.suite.yml (because I misnamed dump.sql on purpose in acceptance.suite.yml and then codeception.yml and it looks like the dump.sql uses the settings in acceptance.suite.yml)? Am I right that the test steps use PDO which use codecepiton.yml? If they are the same, then why do I get the access violation?

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
    - PhpBrowser
    - AcceptanceHelper
    - Db
config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'https://site.com'
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx'
        user: 'xxx'
        password: 'xxx'
        dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
        populate: 'true'
        cleanup: 'true'
```

**codeception.yml**

```
actor: Tester
paths:
tests: tests
log: tests/_output
data: tests/_data
helpers: tests/_support
settings:
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
colors: true
memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
enabled: [PhpBrowser,Db]
config:
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx'
        user: 'xxx'
        password: 'xxx'
        dump: 'test/_data/dump.sql'
        populate: 'true'
        cleanup: 'true'
```

**dump.sql**
CREATE TABLE xxx ... <

**Error:**
[Codeception\Exception\Module]
  (Exception in Db) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Y
  ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
  our MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '∩╗┐CREATE TABLE `f

Answer (score 0):

```
 ∩╗┐ CREATE TABLE
```

Looks like these extraneous characters are being prepended to your `CREATE TABLE` statement. Get rid of those and you should be good to go ...

Comment: I noticed that too, but when I open the dump.sql file, I do not see that.  When I copy the contents inside of dump.sql and paste into mysql, it runs fine.  The CREATE was generated inside of mysql.

Comment: Can you try doing something like this to strip extraneous characters from your dump.sql file:
alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix

...and check if that works?

Comment: I went to notepad++ > encoding> changed from UTF8 to ANSI> Save> reran, and it worked for now.